# Asp.net WebApi can be done without knockoutjs or angular js?

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

Web API without client side libraries like Angularjs/knockoutjs e.t.c?

In asp.net web api

Comment: Please be more clear when asking.

Comment: Please be more specific when using the tags. Why did you use routing. Is it the routing aspect that you're asking about? Be more specific. Also try to use more than one tag instead of one huge tag!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question. But let me try to answer it. Yes you can write WebAPI without using javascript libraries. WebAPI are server side code and you can use .Net MVC framework or any preferred server side language to write it. AngularJS/KnockoutJS are used to consume these api from client side and if you have preferences you can use other libraries to do the same. Ho

Comment: Do you have some links to check?

Comment: As mentioned, it is a server-side API. I know that a lot of examples use client-side API's to consume Web API services but what is it that makes you think that the JS libraries you mentioned has to be used?

Comment: Here is another one:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549152/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Web-API